# T-SQL Hierarchy to duplicate Dependent Objects tree view in SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql, treeview, hierarchy

Id like to map the calling stack from one master stored procedure through its hundreds of siblings. i can see it in the dialog, but cannot copy or print it, but couldnt trap anythiing worthwhile in proflier.
do you know what sproc fills that treeview? i must be a recursive CTE that reads syscomments or information_schema.routines, but its beyond my chops, though i *can* imagine it 
thanks in advance
drew

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at the source code for [sp_depends (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx).

In SQL Server Management Studio:
go to the "master" database
and then "Programmability"
then "Stored Procedures"
then "System Stored Procedures"
then "sys.sp_depends"

In sp_depends's code, there are queries on the tables you'd need to hit to build output like you are after.